# El if siempre se va al else

Tags: c#, visual-studio

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int a;
         Class1 digitoverificador = new Class1();
        a = digitoverificador.Ce(textBox1.Text);
        
        string num = "";
        num = textBox1.Text;
        
        for (int x = 0; x < num.Length; x++)
        {
        }

        if (a==num[9])
        {
            DataGridViewRow newRow1 = new DataGridViewRow();
            newRow1.CreateCells(dataGridView1);
            newRow1.Cells[0].Value = textBox1.Text;
            newRow1.Cells[1].Value = textBox2.Text;
            newRow1.Cells[2].Value = textBox3.Text;
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(newRow1);

            DataGridViewRow newRow = new DataGridViewRow();
            newRow.CreateCells(dataGridView3);
            newRow.Cells[0].Value = textBox1.Text;
            newRow.Cells[1].Value = textBox2.Text;
            newRow.Cells[2].Value = textBox3.Text;
            newRow.Cells[3].Value = textBox4.Text;
            newRow.Cells[4].Value = comboBox1.Text;
            newRow.Cells[5].Value = dateTimePicker1.Text;
            newRow.Cells[6].Value = textBox5.Text;
            newRow.Cells[7].Value = textBox6.Text;
            newRow.Cells[8].Value = comboBox2.Text;
            newRow.Cells[9].Value = comboBox3.Text;
            newRow.Cells[10].Value = comboBox4.Text;
            newRow.Cells[11].Value = comboBox5.Text;
            newRow.Cells[12].Value = comboBox6.Text;
            newRow.Cells[13].Value = textBox7.Text;
            newRow.Cells[14].Value = textBox8.Text;
            dataGridView3.Rows.Add(newRow);
            MessageBox.Show("CEDULA VALIDA");

        }
        else
        {

            DataGridViewRow newRow2 = new DataGridViewRow();
            newRow2.CreateCells(dataGridView2);
            newRow2.Cells[0].Value = textBox1.Text;
            newRow2.Cells[1].Value = textBox2.Text;
            newRow2.Cells[2].Value = textBox3.Text;

            dataGridView2.Rows.Add(newRow2);


            MessageBox.Show("CEDULA INVALIDA");
            MessageBox.Show("el digito verificador es " + a);



        }

    }
}
```

}

[image: No importa que ingrese un dato verdadero siempre se va al else, asi que quisiera saber que es lo que falta o que podria modificarle :C]

aqui el problema

Alguien que me puede decir en que puede modificarlo ya que ya llevo un buen tiempo tratando de entender que falta, El codigo es sobre si el digito verificador coincide con el ultimo digito de la cedula que se ingreso los datos iran donde dice datos validos pero caso contrario ira en cedulas invalidas pero siempre se va a las cedulas invalidas
Les agradeceria de antemano si me dicen como solucionar el problema.
Ojala me haya dado a entender. Buena noche

Comment: Y que devuelve digitoVerificador.Ce?

Comment: digitoVerificador.Ce es una clase para calcular el digito verificador de una cedula. Por ejemplo si mi cedula es "0803758895" el digito verificador es el ultimo digito o sea "5" y si es valido pero si ingreso "0803758892"el ultimo digito es "2" y no es valido. Lo que quiero hacer es comparar esos dos ultimos digitos para asi separarlo de cedulas validas e invalidas, por eso comparo la a(que es el digito verificador calculado) con el num[9](que es la posicion donde esta el ultimo digito de la cedula que ingrese en el textbox) pero siempre se me va al else y no se por que :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que sin darte cuenta estas tratando tu string como un array de string y lo que haces es preguntar si "a" es igual al caracter de la posicion 9. lo cual estarias comparando string con int.
Para solucionar esto simplemente puedes `Convert.ToInt32()` y ToString() a tu array

```
 if(Convert.ToInt32(num[9].ToString()) == a)
 {
      //....tu codigo
 }
```

Como consejo, no llames a tus variables a,b,c, colocale un nombre, para saber de que se trata ese valor. Si lo tienes que ver mas abajo del código, te sera mas fácil saber y seguir tu propio código.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias hermano. Talvez la solucion fue simple pero me solucionaste la vida jaja

Comment: Si te servio marcala como aceptada y puntuala.